# Django - Altering a Form field into a choices field and populating dynamically

Tags: python, django, django-forms

In my models I have a char field as per the below:

```
alerting_tier = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
```

However in my form I'm pulling external data that I would like to use a choices for this field. My attempt thus far is not showing errors but is not showing a choice field either, its just a textbook.

```
class DeviceForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Device
        fields = ['site', 'switches', 'hostname', 'serial_no','version', 'template', 'model', 'install_date', \
        'ospf_area','snmp_data','alerting_tier','host_data','solarwinds_id','smartnet','bau', \
        'smartnet_contract_id','smartnet_contract_start_date','smartnet_contract_end_date','alerting_tier']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        site_id = kwargs.pop('site_id', None)
        device_id = kwargs.pop('device_id', None)
        self.is_add = kwargs.pop("is_add", False)
        self.blank_site = kwargs.pop("blank_site", False)
        super(DeviceForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # get the alerting tiers from solarwinds
        swis = solarwinds_conn()
        tier_query = """
            SELECT 
                c.Field,
                c.Value,
                c.DisplayName
            FROM 
                Orion.CustomPropertyValues c
            WHERE
                Field = 'AlertingTier'
        """
        tier_results = swis.query(tier_query)
        tiers = tier_results["results"]
        tier_options = []
        for i in tiers:
            tier_options.append(i['Value'])
        self.fields['alerting_tier'].choices = tier_options
        self.fields['alerting_tier'].widget.choices = tier_options
```

EDIT:

tried the below:

```
    self.fields['alerting_tier'] = forms.Select()
    self.fields['alerting_tier'].choices = tier_options
```

returning error:

```
'Select' object has no attribute 'get_bound_field'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the widget to be `forms.Select` with the choices on the charfield. A charfield expects you to enter text by default... As you'd expect.

Comment: ive added an edit with updated code and am getting a new error

Comment: self.fields['alerting_tier'].widget = forms.Select()

Comment: You didn't change the widget... You changed the form field.